# Android Studio, Button onClick

Tags: android, onclick

This issue was specific to an older version of ANDROID studio. But is no longer a problem for Android 0.8.1.   I may delete the question completely.

I am still experimenting with Android Studio.  I just upgraded to Version 0.2.13, which I understand had some upgrade issues.  I wrestled through them... but I have an issue with Buttons that I did not have prior to the upgrade.

The Button on Click event is giving me this error in the Properties section.

```
Error getting value: ContentElementType: FILE; file:HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html Boolean.TRUE.equals
```

Prior to this version, I would just type in what I wanted to call my click Handler and there would be no problems.  Now,  I can not even select this field in the Properties inspector.

I have also tried to Manually change the onClick handler... but AS will switch my code back to ""

this is what i have so far...

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="<unset>" />
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR... With no luck
I have also tried restarting AS 
I have tried creating a new ACTIVITY, confirming that it has both a class and Layout file.  and working from that...
I have Manually changed the line `android:onClick="<unset>" />` to `android:onClick="doSomething" />`
and added a `doSomething` function in my code.

/////////////////////////////////////
I just noticed this on startup...  I think this is related...

```
java.lang.AssertionError: ContentElementType: FILE; file: HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html
    Boolean.TRUE.equals(getUserData(BUILDING_STUB)) = false
    getTreeElement() = Element(FILE)
    vFile instanceof VirtualFileWithId = true
    StubUpdatingIndex.canHaveStub(vFile) = false: java.lang.AssertionError: ContentElementType: FILE; file: HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html
    Boolean.TRUE.equals(getUserData(BUILDING_STUB)) = false
    getTreeElement() = Element(FILE)
    vFile instanceof VirtualFileWithId = true
    StubUpdatingIndex.canHaveStub(vFile) = false
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError: ContentElementType: FILE; file: HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html
    Boolean.TRUE.equals(getUserData(BUILDING_STUB)) = false
    getTreeElement() = Element(FILE)
    vFile instanceof VirtualFileWithId = true
    StubUpdatingIndex.canHaveStub(vFile) = false
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask.access$301(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:32)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask$1.run(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:79)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask.run(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: ContentElementType: FILE; file: HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html
    Boolean.TRUE.equals(getUserData(BUILDING_STUB)) = false
    getTreeElement() = Element(FILE)
    vFile instanceof VirtualFileWithId = true
    StubUpdatingIndex.canHaveStub(vFile) = false
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.calcStubTree(PsiFileImpl.java:996)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubProcessingHelperBase.processStubsInFile(StubProcessingHelperBase.java:47)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$2.perform(StubIndexImpl.java:245)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$2.perform(StubIndexImpl.java:236)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.ValueContainer.forEach(ValueContainer.java:60)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.process(StubIndexImpl.java:236)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.get(StubIndexImpl.java:210)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.safeGet(StubIndex.java:73)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.java.stubs.index.JavaFullClassNameIndex.get(JavaFullClassNameIndex.java:48)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.JavaFileManagerBase.findClasses(JavaFileManagerBase.java:133)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.JavaPsiFacadeImpl$PsiElementFinderImpl.findClasses(JavaPsiFacadeImpl.java:297)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.JavaPsiFacadeImpl.findClasses(JavaPsiFacadeImpl.java:147)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.resolveClassPreferringMyJar(ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:187)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.resolveElement(ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.advancedResolveImpl(ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.access$000(ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:40)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl$Resolver.resolve(ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:96)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl$Resolver.resolve(ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:90)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache$2.compute(ResolveCache.java:106)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$2.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:110)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolve(ResolveCache.java:103)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.ResolveCache.resolveWithCaching(ResolveCache.java:131)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.multiResolve(ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:151)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.advancedResolve(ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:141)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassReferenceType.resolveGenerics(PsiClassReferenceType.java:140)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassReferenceType.resolve(PsiClassReferenceType.java:89)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.resolveClassReferenceList(PsiClassImplUtil.java:905)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.getSupersInner(PsiClassImplUtil.java:776)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.getSupers(PsiClassImplUtil.java:734)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsClassImpl.getSupers(ClsClassImpl.java:138)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.InheritanceImplUtil.isInheritorWithoutCaching(InheritanceImplUtil.java:170)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.InheritanceImplUtil.isInheritor(InheritanceImplUtil.java:127)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.InheritanceImplUtil.checkInheritor(InheritanceImplUtil.java:194)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.InheritanceImplUtil.checkInheritor(InheritanceImplUtil.java:176)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.InheritanceImplUtil.isInheritorWithoutCaching(InheritanceImplUtil.java:170)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.InheritanceImplUtil.isInheritor(InheritanceImplUtil.java:127)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.InheritanceImplUtil.isInheritor(InheritanceImplUtil.java:57)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassImpl.isInheritor(PsiClassImpl.java:650)
    at com.intellij.psi.util.InheritanceUtil.isInheritorOrSelf(InheritanceUtil.java:45)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementPresentationUtil.getClassKindImpl(ElementPresentationUtil.java:135)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementPresentationUtil.access$000(ElementPresentationUtil.java:36)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementPresentationUtil$1.compute(ElementPresentationUtil.java:107)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:200)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementPresentationUtil.getClassKind(ElementPresentationUtil.java:112)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementPresentationUtil.getFlags(ElementPresentationUtil.java:51)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementPresentationUtil.createLayeredIcon(ElementPresentationUtil.java:63)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil$2.fun(PsiClassImplUtil.java:323)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil$2.fun(PsiClassImplUtil.java:314)
    at com.intellij.ui.IconDeferrerImpl.defer(IconDeferrerImpl.java:77)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.getClassIcon(PsiClassImplUtil.java:342)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiClassImplUtil.getClassIcon(PsiClassImplUtil.java:329)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiClassImpl.getElementIcon(PsiClassImpl.java:665)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase.computeIconNow(ElementBase.java:136)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase.access$000(ElementBase.java:52)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase$1.fun(ElementBase.java:62)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase$1.fun(ElementBase.java:56)
    at com.intellij.ui.IconDeferrerImpl.defer(IconDeferrerImpl.java:77)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase.computeIcon(ElementBase.java:124)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase.getIcon(ElementBase.java:89)
    at com.intellij.ide.JavaFileIconPatcher.replaceIcon(JavaFileIconPatcher.java:71)
    at com.intellij.ide.JavaFileIconPatcher.patchIcon(JavaFileIconPatcher.java:44)
    at com.intellij.util.IconUtil$1.fun(IconUtil.java:139)
    at com.intellij.util.IconUtil$1.fun(IconUtil.java:121)
    at com.intellij.ui.DeferredIconImpl$2$1.run(DeferredIconImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.ui.IconDeferrerImpl.evaluateDeferred(IconDeferrerImpl.java:112)
    at com.intellij.ui.DeferredIconImpl$2$2.run(DeferredIconImpl.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1171)
    at com.intellij.ui.DeferredIconImpl$2.run(DeferredIconImpl.java:115)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$2.call(JobLauncherImpl.java:139)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$2.call(JobLauncherImpl.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask.access$101(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:32)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask$1.run(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:72)
    ... 4 more



java.lang.AssertionError: ContentElementType: FILE; file: HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html
    Boolean.TRUE.equals(getUserData(BUILDING_STUB)) = false
    getTreeElement() = Element(FILE)
    vFile instanceof VirtualFileWithId = true
    StubUpdatingIndex.canHaveStub(vFile) = false
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.calcStubTree(PsiFileImpl.java:996)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubProcessingHelperBase.processStubsInFile(StubProcessingHelperBase.java:47)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$2.perform(StubIndexImpl.java:245)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$2.perform(StubIndexImpl.java:236)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.ValueContainer.forEach(ValueContainer.java:60)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.process(StubIndexImpl.java:236)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.get(StubIndexImpl.java:210)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.safeGet(StubIndex.java:73)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.java.stubs.index.JavaSuperClassNameOccurenceIndex.get(JavaSuperClassNameOccurenceIndex.java:49)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher$5.compute(JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.java:107)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher$5.compute(JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:939)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.execute(JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.java:104)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.execute(JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.java:48)
    at com.intellij.util.ExecutorsQuery.processResults(ExecutorsQuery.java:43)
    at com.intellij.util.AbstractQuery.forEach(AbstractQuery.java:77)
    at com.intellij.util.UniqueResultsQuery.process(UniqueResultsQuery.java:66)
    at com.intellij.util.UniqueResultsQuery.forEach(UniqueResultsQuery.java:56)
    at com.intellij.psi.search.searches.ClassInheritorsSearch.processInheritors(ClassInheritorsSearch.java:278)
    at com.intellij.psi.search.searches.ClassInheritorsSearch.access$100(ClassInheritorsSearch.java:46)
    at com.intellij.psi.search.searches.ClassInheritorsSearch$1.execute(ClassInheritorsSearch.java:75)
    at com.intellij.psi.search.searches.ClassInheritorsSearch$1.execute(ClassInheritorsSearch.java:53)
    at com.intellij.util.ExecutorsQuery.processResults(ExecutorsQuery.java:43)
    at com.intellij.util.AbstractQuery.forEach(AbstractQuery.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.fillMap(AndroidFacet.java:979)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getInitialClassMap(AndroidFacet.java:946)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getClassMap(AndroidFacet.java:892)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AndroidDomElementDescriptorProvider.getDescriptor(AndroidDomElementDescriptorProvider.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AndroidDomElementDescriptorProvider.getDescriptor(AndroidDomElementDescriptorProvider.java:91)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTagImpl.computeElementDescriptor(XmlTagImpl.java:461)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTagImpl.getDescriptor(XmlTagImpl.java:446)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.checkTagByDescriptor(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:284)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.checkTag(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:164)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.visitXmlToken(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:128)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTokenImpl.accept(XmlTokenImpl.java:44)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.visit(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:724)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$5.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:300)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:419)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$300(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:65)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$7.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:425)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.analyze(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:87)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:422)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$300(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:65)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$7.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:425)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.analyze(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:734)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:422)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$300(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:65)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$7.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:425)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.RefCountHolder.analyze(RefCountHolder.java:298)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.HighlightVisitorImpl.analyze(HighlightVisitorImpl.java:163)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:422)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectHighlights(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:378)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectInformationWithProgress(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:218)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:86)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:61)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:357)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1171)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:345)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:321)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$2.call(JobLauncherImpl.java:139)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$2.call(JobLauncherImpl.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask.access$101(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:32)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask$1.run(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:72)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask.run(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

-----------------------------------  a second stack of errors....

```
    ContentElementType: FILE; file: HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html
    Boolean.TRUE.equals(getUserData(BUILDING_STUB)) = false
    getTreeElement() = Element(FILE)
    vFile instanceof VirtualFileWithId = true
    StubUpdatingIndex.canHaveStub(vFile) = false: ContentElementType: FILE; file: HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html
    Boolean.TRUE.equals(getUserData(BUILDING_STUB)) = false
    getTreeElement() = Element(FILE)
    vFile instanceof VirtualFileWithId = true
    StubUpdatingIndex.canHaveStub(vFile) = false
java.lang.AssertionError: ContentElementType: FILE; file: HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html
    Boolean.TRUE.equals(getUserData(BUILDING_STUB)) = false
    getTreeElement() = Element(FILE)
    vFile instanceof VirtualFileWithId = true
    StubUpdatingIndex.canHaveStub(vFile) = false
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.calcStubTree(PsiFileImpl.java:996)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubProcessingHelperBase.processStubsInFile(StubProcessingHelperBase.java:47)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$2.perform(StubIndexImpl.java:245)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$2.perform(StubIndexImpl.java:236)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.ValueContainer.forEach(ValueContainer.java:60)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.process(StubIndexImpl.java:236)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.get(StubIndexImpl.java:210)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.safeGet(StubIndex.java:73)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.java.stubs.index.JavaSuperClassNameOccurenceIndex.get(JavaSuperClassNameOccurenceIndex.java:49)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher$5.compute(JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.java:107)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher$5.compute(JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:939)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.execute(JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.java:104)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.execute(JavaDirectInheritorsSearcher.java:48)
    at com.intellij.util.ExecutorsQuery.processResults(ExecutorsQuery.java:43)
    at com.intellij.util.AbstractQuery.forEach(AbstractQuery.java:77)
    at com.intellij.util.UniqueResultsQuery.process(UniqueResultsQuery.java:66)
    at com.intellij.util.UniqueResultsQuery.forEach(UniqueResultsQuery.java:56)
    at com.intellij.psi.search.searches.ClassInheritorsSearch.processInheritors(ClassInheritorsSearch.java:278)
    at com.intellij.psi.search.searches.ClassInheritorsSearch.access$100(ClassInheritorsSearch.java:46)
    at com.intellij.psi.search.searches.ClassInheritorsSearch$1.execute(ClassInheritorsSearch.java:75)
    at com.intellij.psi.search.searches.ClassInheritorsSearch$1.execute(ClassInheritorsSearch.java:53)
    at com.intellij.util.ExecutorsQuery.processResults(ExecutorsQuery.java:43)
    at com.intellij.util.AbstractQuery.forEach(AbstractQuery.java:77)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.fillMap(AndroidFacet.java:979)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getInitialClassMap(AndroidFacet.java:946)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getClassMap(AndroidFacet.java:892)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AndroidDomElementDescriptorProvider.getDescriptor(AndroidDomElementDescriptorProvider.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AndroidDomElementDescriptorProvider.getDescriptor(AndroidDomElementDescriptorProvider.java:91)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTagImpl.computeElementDescriptor(XmlTagImpl.java:461)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTagImpl.getDescriptor(XmlTagImpl.java:446)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.checkTagByDescriptor(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:284)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.checkTag(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:164)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.visitXmlToken(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:128)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTokenImpl.accept(XmlTokenImpl.java:44)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.visit(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:724)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$5.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:300)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:419)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$300(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:65)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$7.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:425)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.analyze(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:87)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:422)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$300(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:65)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$7.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:425)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.XmlHighlightVisitor.analyze(XmlHighlightVisitor.java:734)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:422)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$300(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:65)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$7.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:425)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.RefCountHolder.analyze(RefCountHolder.java:298)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.HighlightVisitorImpl.analyze(HighlightVisitorImpl.java:163)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:422)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectHighlights(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:378)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectInformationWithProgress(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:218)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:86)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:61)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:357)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1171)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:345)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:321)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$2.call(JobLauncherImpl.java:139)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$2.call(JobLauncherImpl.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask.access$101(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:32)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask$1.run(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:72)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask.run(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: There was another section of errors I did not notice...

Comment: This issue is no longer a problem with Android Studio 0.8.1

Comment: This still happens in Android Studio 1.3 when you renamee a package. No big harm when you know the solution but not intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, after googling around I found the answer to be simply Invalidating the cache and then restarting Android Studio. **File** > **Invalidate Cache / Restart**. Then from the dialog choose "**Invalidate and restart**"

Comment: This works, but be careful! You will lose your local history

Answer (score 1):

File > Invalidate Cache / Restart. its works for me

Comment: It looks like a comment not an answer.

Comment: Same as the above answer